# Aligning Text that is output to file? Columns

Tags: vb.net, file, text

I have some data which I run through, which generates a textfile.

The data is all pulled correctly, but it doesn't format correctly.

Right now, I am using TAB + Variable to space between each column but it is obviously made uneven as different variables differ in character length. Here is the layout:

```
RECORD       NAME       ADDRESS       TELEPHONE      SOMETHING         SOMETHING

... Data is here.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the text file ultimately used for?  If it's meant to be machine readable only, create a CSV (comma separated values) file instead.

Comment: If you have the luxury of using a DTS Package on the data that was being created, especially if you are pulling the data straight from a DB then I would use it.  Otherwise I would do what Steve mentioned below.

Comment: I like Steve's answer so I wont compete with it, but it is useful in somesituations to know about the `String.PadRight` and `String.PadLeft` methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) is your friend here.
It's very powerfull and gives you the function to align your output.

For example: 
(EDIT: removed the txt prefix because could be confusing, now I suppose that data to be formatted is contained in string vars)

```
Dim result as string 
result = String.Format("{0,-10}{1,-30}{2,-30}{3,-10}{4,20}", Record, Name, Address, Telephone, Something)
```

The result will be aligned to the left in a 10 space column for the first element (txtRecord) and so on for the remainders, the last element will be formatted in a column with 20 space and right aligned

If that's not enough look at [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) to get other useful options

Comment: This seems to be the way, but can you explain what the args do? 
0, -10 ? Is that some kind of way to spread the word? Is -10 characters or ..?

Comment: It is explained in the article Steve linked to.

Comment: 10 is the number of chars for the column size, the sign - (minus) means, align the corresponding argument to the left side of the column. So, the first placeholder {0,-10} means: Insert the first argument (Record var) at the place of 0 inside a column 10 chars wide and align it to the left, so on for the remainder.