# How to align text items with the appearance of a Table

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, string

I am trying to write a formatted text in an email body so that it is well aligned like columns in a table. I tried this code sample, but it’s not displaying aligned data:

```
Dim prod1 As String = "Smartphones"
Dim prod2 As String = "Tablets"
Dim prod3 As String = "Memory Sticks"

Dim qty1 As String = "51"
Dim qty2 As String = "24"
Dim qty3 As String = "108"


Dim show_data1 As New StringBuilder
show_data1.AppendFormat("{0,-10} | {1,10}", prod1, qty1)
show_data1.Append(Environment.NewLine)
show_data1.AppendFormat("{0,-10} | {1,10}", prod2, qty2)
show_data1.Append(Environment.NewLine)
show_data1.AppendFormat("{0,-10} | {1,10}", prod3, qty3)


Dim [to] As New MailAddress("customermail@domain.com") 
Dim [from] As New MailAddress("mycompanymail@domain.com") 
Dim E_mail As New MailMessage([from], [to])

E_mail.Subject = "Order"

E_mail.Body = show_data1.ToString()

E_mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal

Try
  Dim mail_client As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
  mail_client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("companyadr@domain.com", "xxxxxxxxxxx")
  mail_client.EnableSsl = True
  mail_client.Port = 587
  mail_client.Send(E_mail)
  E_mail.Dispose()

  Catch exc As Exception

End Try
```

How can I do it so that the data is well aligned to the left the first column and to the right the second column? Now the output is like this:

- Smartphones     |         51
- Tablets        |         24
- Memory Sticks     |        108

Thank you

Comment: Try  this .. E_mail.IsBodyHtml = true .. This will send email as HTML.. if your HTML format is right then you will get proper format in mail body.

Comment: By output, do you mean `show_data1.ToString()` or what actually shows up in the email?  If the email is being displayed as HTML, multiple spaces are only displayed as one space.  If you want it to look nice with HTML and a non-fixed-width font, you'll need to compose an HTML table to get the alignment.

Comment: By output I mean what displays the email body. And I only want to use plain text, not html table.

Answer (score 0):

As Amneesh said, you have to set IsBodyHtml to true. 
Also, you have to form HTML tags in variable show_data1 as below : (Code is just for your reference)

```
Dim show_data1 As New StringBuilder
show_data1.Append("<table>");
show_data1.Append("<tr><td>" + prod1 + "</td><td> " + qty1 + "</td></tr>")
show_data1.Append("<tr><td>" + prod2 + "</td><td> " + qty2 + "</td></tr>")
show_data1.Append("</table>");
```

Comment: Just a side note, when concatenating strings it's a good idea to use the `&` operator.

Comment: I don't want to use html, just plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to use HTML tables. Just text. The idea is as the following examples:

[Align String with Spaces](http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/)

[Aligning Text that is output to file? Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894773/aligning-text-that-is-output-to-file-columns)

[Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)